# Need to know all the USERNAME that is using the oracle client version less than 19c

Tags: sql, oracle, database-administration

Friends,
Need your assistance here.
I have a requirement to gather all the USERNAME connected to the DB, that is using the oracle client version lesser than 19c.

I am using the below query:

```
SELECT S.SID, S.SERIAL#, S.USERNAME, TO_CHAR(S.LOGON_TIME, 'MON-DD-YYYY HH:MI:SS PM') LOGON_TIME, S.STATUS,
N.AUTHENTICATION_TYPE, N.OSUSER, N.CLIENT_CONNECTION, N.CLIENT_VERSION, N.CLIENT_DRIVER
FROM GV$SESSION  S ,
(SELECT DISTINCT D.SID, D.AUTHENTICATION_TYPE,D.OSUSER,D.CLIENT_CONNECTION,D.CLIENT_VERSION,D.CLIENT_DRIVER FROM GV$SESSION_CONNECT_INFO D) N
WHERE S.SID = N.SID
AND CLIENT_VERSION !='19.0.0.0.0'
AND CLIENT_VERSION !='19.3.0.0.0'
ORDER BY LOGON_TIME,SID;
```

if I use the above query, even for my username - 'APN123', I am getting the client version as unknown. However I am using the oracle client version 19 to connect to the DB.

```
SID  SERIAL# USERNAME LOGON_TIME             STATUS   AUTHENTICATION_TYPE  OSUSER     CLIENT_CONNECTION  CLIENT_VERSION  CLIENT_DRIVER
---------- ---------- ----------- ------------------------- -------- -------------------- ---------- ------------------ --------------- --------------

1203   7853 APN123  SEP-29-2022 02:00:59 PM   ACTIVE   DATABASE   APN123    Heterogeneous      Unknown
1770   7051 APN123  SEP-29-2022 02:00:59 PM   ACTIVE   DATABASE   APN123    Heterogeneous      Unknown
```

1. What is the best way to retrieve all the username and get its client version.
2. what is the impact of using the below combination.

gv$session vs gv$session_connect_info
v$session  vs v$session_connect_info
gv$session vs v$session_connect_info

I know I am missing something here, but not able to identify what it is

Comment: In general when validating client tools accessing the DB, don't forget that not all things connected to the database use the Oracle Client libraries.  For example Oracle's python-oracledb in Thin mode, JDBC Thin, and .NET Managed drivers may have different numbering schemes.  You will need to know which versions of these should be allowed on your system.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
CREATE VIEW xksusecon AS SELECT * FROM SYS.x$ksusecon;

WITH x AS
 (SELECT DISTINCT ksusenum sid,ksuseclvsn,TRIM(TO_CHAR(ksuseclvsn,'xxxxxxxxxxxxxx')) to_c,
   TO_CHAR(ksuseclvsn,'xxxxxxxxxxxxxx') v
  FROM
    sys.xksusecon
 )
 SELECT x.sid,
   DECODE(to_c,'0','Unknown',TO_NUMBER(SUBSTR(v,8,2),'xx') || '.' ||  -- maj_rel
             SUBSTR(v,10,1)      || '.' ||  -- mnt_rel
             SUBSTR(v,11,2)      || '.' ||  -- ias_rel
             SUBSTR(v,13,1)      || '.' ||  -- ptc_set
             SUBSTR(v,14,2)) client_version,  -- port_mnt
   username,program, module
 FROM x, v$session s
 WHERE x.sid like s.sid AND type != 'BACKGROUND'
/
```

You can find all the info with that and then filter more on your criteria.

Answer (score 0):

The other answer is originally from http://marcel.vandewaters.nl/oracle/database-oracle/determine-versions-of-connected-oracle-clients, but is a bit outdated.

For the modern version please take a look at https://ivan.kartik.sk/index.php?controller=post&action=view&id_post=64: Upgrade to 12c: Put a spotlight on Database client
There you find in depth information on how to see client versions connecting to an Oracle DB server, for current connections and you can create a table and trigger to collect old client info over time (as long as you keep the trigger activated).